# Как передать переменную чтобы выводилось имя, а не сам текст Telegram Bot Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть телеграм бот. Я начал его переводить на три языка и создал новый файл со списком сообщений. Сообщение будто-бы выводится без f-строки. Как сделать чтобы выводилось нормально:

- Hello **Ivan Ivanov**.  Welcome to our bot

А не как с переменной:

- Hello **{message.from_user.first_name}
  {message.from_user.last_name}**.  Welcome to our bot

Если дописать **f** к строке в списке сообщений:

```
'hello_with_all_name_en': f' Hello <b><u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u></b>.  Welcome to our bot '
```

То выводится ошибка:`NameError: name 'message' is not defined`, так что, думаю это не вариант

Вот строчка кода:

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, locales.hello_user[f'hello_with_all_name_{BotDB.user_language(message.from_user.id)}'], parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kb.markup_start)
```

А вот список сообщений с файла locales.py:

```
hello_user = {
   'hello_with_all_name_uk': ' Привіт, <b><u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u></b>.  Вітаємо у нашому боті ',
   'hello_with_all_name_ru': ' Привет, <b><u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u></b>.  Поздравляем в нашем сапоге ',
   'hello_with_all_name_en': ' Hello <b><u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u></b>.  Welcome to our bot '
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попробывать реализовать это в формате функции:

```
def hello(message):
    hello_user = {
       'hello_with_all_name_uk': ' Привіт, <b><u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u></b>.  Вітаємо у нашому боті ',
       'hello_with_all_name_ru': ' Привет, <b><u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u></b>.  Поздравляем в нашем сапоге ',
       'hello_with_all_name_en': ' Hello <b><u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u></b>.  Welcome to our bot '
    }
    
    return hello_user["hello_with_all_name_uk"]
```

В эту функцию вы просто передаёте само сообщение в обрабработчике при отправке. Вот пример:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(hello(message))
```

**P.S. - *Не забудьте изменить данные в [] в return в функции hello, на свои с БД!!!***

И также не большая правочка насчёт Вашего словаря, правильние украинский язык назвать **hello_with_all_name_ua**, потомучто **uk** - это **United Kingdom**(*Великобритания*) ;)

Вы можеет попробывать использывать `.format` для выполнения Вашей задачи. Пример использования:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    hello_user = {
       'hello_with_all_name_uk': ' Привіт, <b><u>{} {}</u></b>.  Вітаємо у нашому боті ',
       'hello_with_all_name_ru': ' Привет, <b><u>{} {}</u></b>.  Поздравляем в нашем сапоге ',
       'hello_with_all_name_en': ' Hello <b><u>{} {}</u></b>.  Welcome to our bot '
    }
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, hello_user["hellow_with_all_name_uk"].format(message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name))
```

Если этот пример Вам больше по душе и будет коректно работать в Вашей ситуации, то **не забудьте изменить словарь `hello_user` на поданый в этом примере и использовать для дальнейшей локализации в подобном формате!**

Comment: Оно впринципе работает, но может вы знаете способ без создания функции в списке сообщений?

Comment: я не уверен но Вы можете попробывать использовать вместо f-string, .format(). Сейчас допишу это к своему ответу

Comment: Я добавил правку к своему ответу!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и время, буду сидеть работать) Метод с format сработал отлично. Сообщения всё так-же беру с второго файла

Comment: Всегда рад помочь;)